# Add a custom field in woocommerce attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Does anybody knows what hooks I need to look at if I want to add additional field into woocommerce new attributes page?

I have slug, but I'd like to add icon field where you'll be able to add icon name, and that will be outputted next to the attribute? And that input field should be below the slug input.

I found the woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies function, but I'm not sure how to edit it properly without changing the plugin directly.

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#webhooks

Answer (score 1):

After looking at woo's webhooks I couldn't find anything that would help. But I did notice that when editing the attribute I wished to add a field to there was this in the url: /wp-admin/edit-tags.php?**taxonomy=pa_brand**&post_type=product. Every time an attribute is created Woo creates this as a custom tax. This means you can use this tax to create custom metaboxes.

Either by using this tutorial https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/ or a dev toolkit such as CMB2 : https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2

Hope this helps someone!